# AngularJS : How to disable checkboxes after specified amount is selected?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have checkboxes within loop like below:

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      <h2>  {{item.better}}</h2>
      <span>{{item.startTime}}</span>
      <b>   {{item.lengthTime}}</b>
      <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="item.winner" checklist-value="item">
 </li>
```

I want to set limit so that users could only select maximum 50 checkboxes and not more than that out of (no. of total items in the list i.e 100 or 200 etc.).

How do we accomplish that using angular js ?

Help would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Quadraxas/9nsTd/4/)

```
$scope.checkChanged = function(item){
    if(item.winner) $scope.checked++;
    else $scope.checked--;
}
```

and

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.winner" ng-change="checkChanged(item)" ng-disabled="checked==limit && !item.winner"/>
```

this keeps track of checked with ng-change and disables them if the limit is reached and the checkbox is not checked.

not using $watch because of the possibility of ~200 checkboxes.

edit: sorry forgot to click update on fiddle, it should work now. Also note that limit is set to 4 with `$scope.limit = 4`;

Comment: That works. But it also disables one which are already checked.

Comment: edited fiddle. input html was correct on answer but i forgot to update fiddle. works now.

Comment: This is good solution. What if we use checklist-model directive like here http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/ and injecting whole "item" as array in model. Right now I see that you are checking it off using winner value.

Comment: if you use that directive this way, you will get a `maximum call stack size reached `or something like angular stopping digest loop because it hit an infinite digest loop. Reason for this error is that assigning `item` to `item.winner` results in cyclic structure. This means since `item.winner` is same thing as `item`, `item.winner.winner.winner.winner.winner` is also `item`. This goes infinitely. That directive probably tries to walk this structure and this results in one of the errors above.

Answer (score 1):

you could ask for the number of items and use the `ng-disabled`

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="!item.value && items.length > 50" />
```

#### Update:

as mentioned in the comments, the answer is not correct. But i think you got (and other guys who answered) the right idea how to accomplish what you need. I think, the necessary information for you is to use `ng-disabled`.

I like Aperçu answer most :)

Comment: Only problem is that ng-disabled disables all checkboxes. I also want them ability to unselect and choose again.

Comment: the expression I used can be extended as you wish. you can always use operators like `&&` and `||` to extend it for your needs :)

Comment: items array is not the list of checked items but all items that can be checked, so items.length > 50 makes them all disabled when you have more than 50 items, assuming initially none of them is checked.